# Why is my function not working PHP?

Tags: php

Hey why is my function not working here is the php code, its written in mysql_connect:

```
function isUserLoggedIn() {
    global $conn;
    $sql = "SELECT user_id, password FROM user
            WHERE
            user_id='" . fixstr($loggedInUser->user_id) . "' 
            AND 
            password='" . fixstr($loggedInUser->password) . "' 
            AND
            active = 1
            LIMIT 1";

    $res = mysql_query($sql);
    $rs = mysql_fetch_array($res);  

    if($loggedInUser($res) == NULL)
    {
        return false;
    }
    else
    {
        //Query the database to ensure they haven't been removed or possibly banned?
        if(returns_result($sql) > 0)
        {
                return true;
        }
        else
        {
            //No result returned kill the user session, user banned or deleted
            $loggedInUser->userLogOut();

            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

The connection does return an active window but is not able to connect to any of the functions does anybody know why my code is not working?

Comment: Hey! Don't know, but I suggest you check out [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php).

Comment: *sidenote:* stop using deprecated `mysql_*` functions. use MySQLi or PDO instead.

Comment: `$loggedInUser` is not global, therefor the function cannot access it.

Answer (score 2):

`$loggedInUser` is not in the scope.

You can do one of the following:

- inject `$loggedInUser` through method parameter.
  Eg) `function isUserLoggedIn($loggedInUser)`
- locally construct or define `$loggedInUser`. 
  Eg) `$loggedInUser = (new LoggedInUserFactory)->buildLoggedInUser();`
- declare `global $loggedInUser;`

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what [Kita](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18840527/3240) wrote,  it's also not known whether $conn is valid, and perhaps `if($loggedInUser($res) == NULL)` should be `$rs` not `$res`?  I don't know the function definition so I can't say for sure, but it looks like that's more likely

Comment: Also the ```$sql``` in ```if(returns_result($sql) > 0)``` could be replaced with ```$rs``` to make more sense :)